# How should I implement ITouchArea.convertSceneToLocalCoordinates() for AndEngine?

Tags: java, android, andengine, coordinate-transformation

I'm using AndEngine and I'm creating a class that manages a bunch of sprites.
The class needs to perform some actions when the user touches it, so I made it implement the ITouchArea interface.

I defined the method contains:

```
 @Override
 public boolean contains(float pX, float pY) {
    if(     pX >= this.mXCenterPosition - X_DIMENSION/2 &&
            pX <= this.mXCenterPosition + X_DIMENSION/2 && 
            pY >= this.mYCenterPosition - Y_DIMENSION/2 &&
            pY <= this.mYCenterPosition + Y_DIMENSION/2)
        return true;
    return false;
 }
```

and this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
        float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY)
```

What I still miss is this:

```
public float[] convertSceneToLocalCoordinates(float pX, float pY)
```

Without defining it, or returning null, the program crashes. I tried to look at how it is implemented in other classes, but I didn't really understood what it does, and I don't know what it is its function, so I don't know how to implement it. The area of the class is a simple rectangle.

What should this method do? How would I implement it?

Comment: Just a note: Your `contains` method can be implemented without any `if`, just `return   pX >= this.mXCenterPosition - X_DIMENSION/2 &&
     pX <= this.mXCenterPosition + X_DIMENSION/2 && 
     pY >= this.mYCenterPosition - Y_DIMENSION/2 &&
    pY <= this.mYCenterPosition + Y_DIMENSION/2;` (with linebreaks like in your example, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method should be converting a coordinate in scene space to local space (of the `Entity`). If there's only translation on your `Entity`, then you would simply subtract `mX` and `mY` from the given x and y coordinates respectively.

[In the image, the entity's (mX, mY) is (300, 100)]
[image]

With rotation and scale it'll be using the same concepts. It's just that the x and y axes will be rotated/scaled, and thus the `Sprite` will also be rotated/scaled. You'll probably want to implement this using a Transformation object (the same way `Entity` does). See `Entity.convertLocalToSceneCoordinates(final float pX, final float pY, final float[] pReuse)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. The Sprite will not be scaled or rotated, so you really give me the solution of my problem! Thanks!